# connect to a filemaker database with c#

Tags: c#, filemaker

I need to connect to a database Filemaker 15, not mine. I have never used this database and do not know how to connect. I would avoid, if possible, to use odbc. Can you give me some advice? Thank you

Comment: http://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fsharing-via-odbc-jdbc.html%23wwconnect_header

Comment: thanks @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 0):

You have more options, if trigger data exchange from FileMaker.  In c# you could provide some XML and read it from FileMaker via HTTPPOST.

~Jens

Comment: Just a small correction: this will work on a file served with FileMaker server and as far as I remember, xml functionality is GET.